# Enabling Android Retail Demo

Tags: android, nexus, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to get into retail demo mode on nexus 5x, Android Oreo.
I've read this article:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/retail-mode

It seems like it just should be on the bottom of the list of the language suggestions, after factory reset - which it doesn't.

After looking into it, it seems like its package (com.android.retaildemo) wasn't exist, so I've put the apk on system/priv-app. Still - no success.

Does someone know how to get into retail mode ?

Going into it's code I've found that the application started disabled, so in order to start DemoPlayer activity, i had to make it enabled and then i could see the demo mode app... but I don't want to use the adb for this purpose, I'd like to do it the "right" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok if someone ever gets into finding out how to do this I have an answer for you:

After a long research, the way to get into retail mode is either from the languages selection after factory reset (the last item on the list) or changing the settings via adb..
I didn't have the demo suggestion on the language selection screen so I could only use the adb to simulate it...

getting into demo mode:
adb shell settings put global device_demo_mode 1

leaving demo mode:
adb shell settings put global device_demo_mode 0

Just don't forget to put the retaildemo.apk into system/priv-app before that.
This app only shows the "teaser"/"promo" for the demo mode, the demo mode launches the app and show an oem customised video or just a screen that tapping on it leads to the demo guest user.

link to retaildemo.apk:
https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/retail-demo-5/

Answer (score 3):

who says that enabling the app in the adb is not the right way?  after all - the retail app is Google's open souce project which should be use as a baseline for OEM's wishing to enable demo experience.  right?    if so - the right way might be - cloning the project and change it to be enable by default :->